# Ideals of subsets in $k[x_1,..,x_n]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $k$ is algebraically closed field and $X_1, X_2 \subset \mathbb{A}^n_k$. Show that
$$
I(X_1 \cap X_2)=\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}. 
$$

I thought the first thing to do was to use the Nullstellensatz Hilbert to vanish with that square root:

$$
\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}= I(Z(\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}))= I(Z(I(X_1)+I(X_2))).
$$

I thought it was easier to show that
$$
I(X_1 \cap X_2)=I(Z(I(X_1)+I(X_2))).
$$ 
But I could not get out of here. Maybe it was a bad start. Does anyone suggest anything to me? A new beginning or how to get out of that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to show that $ X_1 \cap X_2 = Z(I(X_1) + I(X_2)).$

- Suppose $p \in X_1 \cap X_2$. Any element $f \in I(X_1) + I(X_2)$ takes the form $f = g + h$, where $g \in I(X_1)$ and $h \in I(X_2)$. So $f(p) = g(p) + h(p) = 0$. Hence $p \in Z(I(X_1) + I(X_2))$.
- Suppose $p \in Z(I(X_1) + I(X_2))$. Any $g \in I(X_1)$ is also in $I(X_1) + I(X_2)$, so $g(p) = 0$ for all $g \in I(X_1)$; hence $p \in Z(I(X_1)) = X_1$. By a similar argument, $p \in X_2$. So $p \in X_1 \cap X_2$.

Comment: For me, it was a great help. But I understand that you have used $X_1$ and $X_2$ are algebraic sets to conclude that $ Z(I(X_1))=X_1$ and $Z(I(X_2))=X_2$. Could we solve for $X_1$ and $X_2$ as sets of points only?

Comment: @Manoel Not sure off the top of my head. Unfortunately I have to go - perhaps someone else can help?